# How to organize projectile, image-dired, tramp temporary files

Tags: emacs, elisp

I always try to keep my .emacs.d neat. So I put all the customization 
files into var folder.

So the question is how to let Emacs Know the default files of **projectile**, 
**tramp** and **image-dired** should go into my var folder? -- As shown in the figure.

Many thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might need to customize these files one by one yourself, for example, to put `projectile-bookmarks.eld` into your `var/`:

```
(defvar my-data-directory
  (expand-file-name "var/" user-emacs-directory))

(setq projectile-known-projects-file
      (expand-file-name "projectile-bookmarks.eld" my-data-directory))
```

I am not sure if all files you need is customizable.

Comment: For image-dired, try `(setq image-dired-dir (expand-file-name "image-dired/" my-data-directory))`